# How can I call ajax before display datepicker in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

Look at this : https://codepen.io/positivethinking639/pen/mddejJN

My script of vue like this :

```
data: () => ({
    modalTest: false,
    dateTest: null,
    time: null,
    allowedTimes: ['8:30 am','9:00am','10:30am','1:30pm','3:30 pm']
}),
methods: { 
    saveData() {
        this.$refs.dialogTest.save(this.dateTest)
    },
    allowedDates: val => parseInt(val.split('-')[2], 10) % 2 === 0,
    setTime(time) {
        this.time = time
    }
```

I want before call datepicker, I call ajax first

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the dialog `button` outside and add a `@click` method for showing the dialog

### Your Code

```
<template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
     <v-btn color="success" dark v-on="on">call date</v-btn>
</template>
```

### New Code

**Html**

```
<v-btn color="success" dark @click="showDate">call date</v-btn>
```

**Code**

```
showDate(){
    console.log("Ajax calling");
    this.modalTest = true;
}
```

Here the [pen](https://codepen.io/M4xJ4mb0/pen/RwwWYXQ)

Answer (score 2):

@Max proposal is not fully answers the question.

Let's add new data property which will trigger the show of calendar component:

```
isAjaxCompl: false,
```

Move the button out of template to directly change dialog `v-model`:

```
<v-btn color="success" @click="openDialog()">call date</v-btn>
```

Make the function which will be fired on dialog open:

```
    openDialog() {
      this.modalTest = true;   
      axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/users?delay=1').then((response) => {
        this.isAjaxCompl = true;
      })
    },
```

Finally, add `v-if` which will show calendar component only when `axios` get the response:

```
 <v-date-picker v-if="isAjaxCompl" v-model="dateTest" scrollable :allowed-dates="allowedDates">
```

Link to the corresponding CodePen:
https://codepen.io/RobbyFront/pen/RwwWewM